# Tomcat deployment of application error: LifecycleException

Tags: tomcat, deployment, war

I can not deploy an application (.war) in tomcat 8. 
I'm on a Windows 2008 server. I installed tomcat 8.0.5. I downloaded a war file (the application that I want to install is GeoSource Version 2.9.2.0 ([here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geonetwork/files/GeoSource%20-%20french%20only/GeoSource2.9/))). 
I copy and paste the war. In tomcat (/ tomcat / webapps). In the management interface applications tomcat, I see that GeoSource appears, but when I want to start, tomcat returns me an error:

```
FAIL - Application for the context path / GeoNetwork could not be started 
FAIL - The exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException.. Failed to start component StandardEngine [Catalina] StandardHost [localhost] StandardContext [/ GeoNetwork]] was encountered
```

Where is the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: And the rest of the error message is ... ?

Comment: Here : http://pastie.org/9087119

Answer (score 0):

And there is the problem:

> Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader
>   (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) previously
>   initiated loading for a different type with name
>   "javax/servlet/ServletConfig"

It looks like you have a copy of (some of?) the Servlet API classes in your webapp. Remove them.

Answer (score 0):

The jars in your WAR file contain either servlet-api.jar or javaee-api.jar.  Do not include those, they are included in tomcat/lib and will conflict if found anywhere else in the classpath.